# Lerna.js Setup in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, lerna, monorepo

I am trying to set up my project based on MonoRepo for that I have used lerna.js now as far as I know lerna.js work as follows.

## For Dev

1. Create lerna.json and update all packages and workspace details to package.json and lerna.json
2. run yarn or npm client as usual you do.
3. any folder inside packages/ will be treated as node_module so you can directly call them.

Now running my application as dev works fine but when to build or transpile my es6 code using Babel for production than lerna.json doesn't work right following are problems which are making me confused about how to use it.

1. Do I have to Publish all my packages to npm for using them in production?
2. running `lerna` Bootstrap links packages but when I view my package inside node_modules it still contains es6 code..due to this node application throws an error for using import statement which node didn't understand unless you use experimental flag.

**Following is the Example:**

1. lerna.json

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent",
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true
}
```

2. packages Directory

```
packages/
  context/
  dyna_modules/
  www/
```

3. npm scripts

```
    "clean": "lerna clean --yes && rimraf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json yarn.lock",
    "build::js": "babel ./packages --out-dir ./build/packages/ --ignore node_modules",
    "build::nonjs": "babel package.json prisma.yml Dockerfile docker-compose.yml .env --out-dir ./build --copy-files && babel ./packages/routes --out-dir ./build/packages/routes --copy-files",
    "build": "rm -rf ./build && mkdir ./build && npm run build::js && npm run build::nonjs",
    "dev:nodemon": "DEBUG=*,-babel,-babel:*,-express:*,-nodemon:*,-nodemon,-snapdragon:*,-finalhandler,-follow-redirects nodemon -L --exec babel-node --inspect index.js",
    "dev": "yarn dev:nodemon --ignore-engines",
    "prestart": "npm run build && lerna bootstrap",
    "start": "cd ./build && node ./packages/www/index.js",
```

## Problem

Running yarn start always fails with error for using the Import statement. During the inspection, I found out that all my `packages/modules` inside `node_module` contain es6 syntax instead of a trans-piled code.

Comment: I think you should go with babel

Comment: Nope..its hard to trans pile modules every time new build is generated...